# MLE estimation for exponentially distributed

Tags: statistics

A postal clerk has an operating time t that is exponentially distributed with density

$f\left(x\right)\:=\:\lambda e−^{\lambda x},\:x\:\ge \:0$

where $\lambda $ is an unknown parameter

Given $n$ observations $t_1,.\:.\:.\:,\:t_n$, find the probability maximization estimate $\overline{\lambda } $ for the unknown parameter $\lambda $. Find a numeric value for $\overline{\lambda } $ when you have the following 10 observed operating times: ten: $2, 1.4, 2.0, 0.5, 0.7, 2.0, 1.3, 1.1, 1.8, 0.2,$ where the unit of time is one minute.

To find the $\overline{\lambda } $ I just took the derivative of $n$ observations $t_1,.\:.\:.\:,\:t_n$ and found out that it was

$0=n\frac{1}{\lambda }-\left(t_1+t_2+......+t_n\right)$

$\lambda \:\:=\left(t_1+t_2+......+t_n\right)$

$\overline{\lambda } $ = 13

Would this be correct?

And to find a numeric value for $\overline{\lambda } $ what do I do then?

Comment: The mle for an exponential distributed variable is $\hat \lambda=\large{\frac{n}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i}}$

Answer (score 1):

$0=n\frac{1}{\hat \lambda }-\left(t_1+t_2+\cdots+t_n\right)$

does not suggest $\hat \lambda =\left(t_1+t_2+\cdots+t_n\right)$

but $\hat \lambda = \dfrac{n}{\left(t_1+t_2+\cdots+t_n\right)} $